# Why and When we should implement snd_pcm_ops?

Tags: linux, alsa

I don't know whether I can ask here or not.

I am trying to understand the Alsa drivers in the Linux.

I have an idea on codec driver, machine driver and platform driver.

**Codec driver:** *This driver used for the codec specific stuff.*

**Machine driver:** *This driver binds the codec driver and the platform driver.*

**Platform driver:** *This driver registers the dai and DMA related to the platform.*

Recently I found a platform driver where they used `snd_pcm_ops` and they didn't register any dai ops and DMA related stuff in their probe.

```
/* define all pcm ops of hi6210 pcm */
static struct snd_pcm_ops hi6210_pcm_ops = {
    .open       = hi6210_pcm_open,
    .close      = hi6210_pcm_close,
    .ioctl      = snd_pcm_lib_ioctl,
    .hw_params  = hi6210_pcm_hw_params,
    .hw_free    = hi6210_pcm_hw_free,
    .prepare    = hi6210_pcm_prepare,
    .trigger    = hi6210_pcm_trigger,
    .pointer    = hi6210_pcm_pointer,
};
/* Code from an Android mobile kernel */
```

I just want to understand when and why we should register our platform driver using those `snd_pcm_ops`.

I found a [doc](http://www.alsa-project.org/~tiwai/writing-an-alsa-driver/ch05s06.html) , I am unable to understand the situation where we can use them.

We never used those in the RPI i2s driver.

Can anyone explain me about this?

Comment: A driver that does not mention any `*_soc_*` functions probably is a 'normal' ALSA driver.

Comment: Did little study and understood that they are not using the generic DMA driver and doing the things that  generic DMA do by themselves.